# QBO - Issue in SpecifyOperatorOption Query Filter

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

```
Code :  
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery qboAccQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery();

qboAccQuery.CreateTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-20);
qboAccQuery.SpecifyOperatorOption(Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterProperty.CreateTime,
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterOperatorType.AFTER);

qboAccQuery.CreateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;     
qboAccQuery.SpecifyOperatorOption(Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterProperty.CreateTime,
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterOperatorType.BEFORE);

qboAccQuery.PageNumber = 1;
qboAccQuery.ResultsPerPage = 15;

List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account> qboAccounts = 
qboAccQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account>    (co ntext).ToList<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account>();
```

getting this request body Filter=CreateTime :AFTER: 2013-06-19T15:28:56+05:30 & Sort=CreateTime AToZ&PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=100

but it generate exception InvalidTokenException : {"Unauthorized"}

```
Exception :
Intuit.Ipp.Exception.InvalidTokenException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Unauthorized
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=401
  StackTrace:
     at Intuit.Ipp.Exception.IdsExceptionManager.HandleException(IdsException idsException)
     at Intuit.Ipp.Services.QboService.Get[T](IQboQuery qboQuery, String simpleQuery, Boolean isQuerySpecified)
     at Intuit.Ipp.Services.ServiceExtensions.ExecuteQuery[T](IQuery query, ServiceContext serviceContext)
     at QbSync.QuickBooksCustomers.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: It could be the syntax of the query. You can test the query easily here in the API Explorer https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiName=V2QBO#Account

Comment: i tested it, it create problem only with dates

Answer (score 1):

The SDK is not encoding the request body correctly, so you will need to use DevDefined and deserialize the response with the SDK. Code sample: https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6024616